# Rails Console - Delete all records that don't have any associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a Model `House`, and a house can `have_many` `Room`s.

I would like to delete all records of `House` that have no `Room`s.

I've tried

```
House.includes(:room).having('room.id IS NULL')
```

which errors, as does

```
House.all().where(:room.count == 0)
```

and many other things that I've tried along the same lines.

I'm probably missing something really straightforward, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The association should be plural

```
House.includes(:rooms).where(rooms: { id: nil }).count
```

And you should be able to delete them using

```
ids = House.includes(:rooms).where(rooms: { id: nil }).pluck(:id)
House.where(id: ids).delete_all

# Note: I'm leaving this as reference. It seems to raise an error.
# House.includes(:rooms).where(rooms: { id: nil }).delete_all
```

Otherwise you can work with a little bit of pure SQL and perform a `DELETE` statement directly using a `join`.

Comment: This is getting the count correctly, but throwing a no such column: rooms.id: error on the delete_all. It looks like it's trying to find rooms.id in House even though House > has_many rooms?

Comment: Not sure how `delete_all` works internally. You can always perform two separate queries, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Can you try to replace the `includes(:rooms)` with `joins(:rooms)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
House.includes(:rooms).where('rooms.id IS NULL')
```